# ListViewRemovalAnimation Google devbyte example - scrolling inabilities

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

**Preface**

I have implemented  [ListViewRemovalAnimation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/28b127ec1e5af575a74af679a85420) example from Google to my code, and added some other functions, like single and long clicks. But I have found out, that ListView is behaving strangely on some occasions. Firstly I have thought, that it is my fault - caused by me implementing other functionalities. But I have found out that this exact behavior can be simulated in almost the same example code.

**Problem**

Removing item from the bottom when all available/left items are visible, makes scrolling nearly impossible (in newly pupulated ListView - see code).  Please follow [video](https://vid.me/PuwG)

On some occasions - which are hardly describable, touch responses are completely lost and only app restart helps.

Sometimes, when in broken scroll list, removing items from the center of the list helps. Newly created list is again scroll able.

**Code**

I have taken Googles example code [android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/jb-mr1-dev/samples/devbytes/animation/ListViewRemovalAnimation)  which is first commit https://github.com/cletriomis/ListViewRemovalAnimation
And added some lines to simulate this bottom removal and following inability to scroll - last commit.

**Testing environment**

Device: Samsung SM-T700 - Android: AndroidVersion 4.4.2
Android 5.0.1 armeabi-v7a (arm emulation in Androd Studio)

**Info-updates**
*v01* - using "setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_deletion);" when repopulating ListView with new data helps, but only in this easy example. Any idea why does it help?